# SelectElement in Selenium 2.39 fails

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

```
I use to pick items from drop-down menus using `SelectElement` class in my automated tests  and they worked just fine until I upgraded to Selenium 2.39 .

 ALL (!) tests that use this class fail and I get error message: `"Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with".`


    I presume there is a bug in 2.39. Tested on Firefox 26.0. Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

//Here's a piece of my HTML:

    <select id="CodGender" class="ui-selectmenu-element" name="CodGender" data-val-required="Mandatory attribute" data-val="true" aria-disabled="false">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="M">Male</option>
        <option value="Z">Female</option>
    </select>

//and here's how I'd pick an item from the drop-down:

    {   var dropDownList = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("[@id='CodGender']"));
        var selectElement = new SelectElement(dropDownList);
        selectElement.SelectByText("Male");
    }
```

---

Here's a quick watch window result for "dropDownList" after passing the second line of code:
    Displayed false
    Enabled true
    Location {X = -1658 Y = 791}
    Selected false
    Size    {Width = 200 Height = 30}
    TagName "select"
    Text    ""

... and here's the one for "selectElement" :
    AllSelectedOptions Count = 1
    IsMultiple false
    Options Count = 3
    [0] {OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxWebElement}
    [1] {OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxWebElement}
    [2] {OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxWebElement}

... then option No. 2 looks like:
    [OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxWebElement] {OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxWebElement}
    Displayed false
    Enabled true
    Location {X = -1656 Y = 851}
    Selected false
    Size {Width = 197 Height = 16}
    TagName "option"
    Text    ""
...

Comment: Even through your own debugging, the `select` isn't visible. So what must a user do to make it visible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need an explicit wait for the element to become visible or enabled.

The fact you do not get a NoSuchElementException indicates that webdriver is aware of the element's presence. I would suggest adding a wait for the dropdown to be visible, and for safety you can also add a wait for the desired text to be visible. This will stop webdriver trying to select the option before the option is available.

Comment: I debugged the code several times, allowing all elements plenty of time to get visible. Didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer that came from James of Selenium Team:
He thoroughly explained the mentioned issue as well as provided some guides how to fix it ...

"
Okay, what's probably happening here is that your site is using some sort of JavaScript UI widget framework (jQueryUI maybe?), which simulates a drop-down by use of  and  elements, but stores the actual data inside a  element. The  element holding the actual data is not visible, probably hidden by the 'ui-selectmenu-element' CSS class.

WebDriver cannot interact with (click, send keys to, etc.) hidden elements, full stop. The fact that you *could* manipulate the invisible  element in previous versions of WebDriver was a bug, which has now been fixed.

You have three options now. First, you can use the UI elements actually visible in the UI to select the appropriate values. Second, you could use JavaScript, along with the API of whatever JavaScript UI toolkit you're using, to programmatically manipulate the "dropdown" control. For either of these two options, you won't be able to use the SelectElement class to manipulate the control, because the elements you're manipulating won't be  elements. Finally, you could somehow cause the actual  element to become visible, but you'll need to figure out the inner workings of your UI widget framework to manipulate the  element to become visible.
"